# Static variable in php is not working as expected in a recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, static-variables

I am using static variable in php. Ideally this should display 1 to 10.

But it is not. Why is it so ?

```
test(10);
function test($a)
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count;
    if ($count < $a) {
        echo 'in if ' . $count;
        test($count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire class code, with an example perhaps, bit hard to diagnose without more info.

Comment: You probably want `test($a)`, not `test($count)`.

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong variable in your if. If you debug it you would see that function triggers only twice instead of 10.

change

```
if ($count < $a) {
    echo 'in if ' . $count;
    test($count);
}
```

to

```
if ($count < $a) {
    echo 'in if ' . $count;
    test($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to print 1 to 10

```
function test($a)
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count."====".$a;
    if ($count < $a) {
        echo 'in if ' . $count;
        test($a);
    }

}
```